# Show that $AB$ and $B$ are independent.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

$(A, B)$ are absolute continous random variable, with density $f_{A,B}(a,b) = be^{-b(a+1)}, \ a,b >0$. Show that $AB$ and $B$ are independent.

I believe that they are independent if  $f_{AB,B}=f_{AB}f_{B}$.  I can find $f_B$ by integrating $A$ out:

$$f_B=\int_0^\infty be^{-b(a+1)}da=e^{-b}, \quad b>0$$

But I dont know how to find $f_{AB}$ or $f_{AB,B}$. This is where I need some help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the formula for the probability density of a transformed random variables:
For continuous random variable $X\in R^n$ and continuously differentiable function $y=G(x)$
$$
f_Y(y)=(\det J(x))^{-1}f_X(x)=(\det J(G^{-1}(y)))^{-1}f_X(G^{-1}(y)),
$$
where $Y=G(X)$ and $J(x)=G'(x)$ is a Jacobi matrix.

For your particular case $(x,y)=G(a,b)=(ab,b)$ (so $G^{-1}(x,y)=(x/y,y)$) and
$$
J(a,b)=\begin{pmatrix}b&a\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\implies\det J(a,b)=b
$$
$$
f_{AB,B}(x,y)=\frac1bf_{A,B}(a,b)=e^{-b(a+1)}I(a>0,b>0)=e^{-ab-b}I(a>0,b>0)=e^{-x-y}I(x>0,y>0).
$$
Hence $X=AB$ and $Y=B$ are independent.